# Serving to a P.O. Box in Ontario

Tags: canada, small-claims-court, ontario

Assisting a relative with a small claims case (Ontario, Canada).

We are to serve the defendant's representative (a paralegal) that is operating under a P.O. Box in another city.

Are we legally allowed to serve by sending documents to the P.O. box with tracking to confirm it's been delivered?

Comment: This sounds as if you were assuming that you could serve process by putting the documents in the mail yourself which sounds a bit odd (however, my background is in a civil law jurisdiction). I know for sure that international mail service under the Hague Service Convention can only be initiated by the court; If you believe that domestic mail service is different from that, you should make sure that this is actually the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find the following excerpts from the rules useful.

Rules of Civil Procedure, R.R.O. 1990, Reg. 194:

16.01 (1) Originating Process

> An originating process shall be served personally as provided in rule
>   16.02 or by an alternative to personal service as provided in rule 16.03

16.03 Alternatives to Personal Service:

> (4) Service of a document may be made by sending a copy of the
>   document together with an acknowledgment of receipt card (Form 16A) by
>   mail to the last known address of the person to be served, but service
>   by mail under this subrule is only effective as of the date the sender
>   receives the card.

16.04 (4) Service by Mail to Last Known Address

> Service of a document may be made by sending a copy of the document
>   together with an acknowledgment of receipt card (Form 16A) by mail to
>   the last known address of the person to be served, but service by mail
>   under this subrule is only effective as of the date the sender
>   receives the card.

Manner of Service by Mail

> 16.06 (1) Where a document is to be served by mail under these rules, 
>   a copy of the document shall be served by regular lettermail or by
>   registered mail.

https://www.ontario.ca/laws/regulation/900194